# Rails migration deleted entries from associated tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-2, rails-migrations

In rails (2.3.5) I have 2 associated models:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :studys, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Study < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name, :report_id
  belongs_to :report
end
```

I'm running a migration on the reports table:

```
class AddReportUsername< ActiveRecord::Migration

def self.up
  add_column :reports, :username, :text, :limit => 20
end
```

This migration deletes all entries in my `studies` table.

My assumption is that the `ALTER TABLE` command invoked by the `add_column` deletes the `reports` table and recreate it with the new column. Because of the association between the `Study` and `Report` models, the dependent `studies`are destroyed.

If this is true - is there a way to prevent Rails from doing that? Or, can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: You can write this in your migration's `self.up` method: `execute "ALTER TABLE reports ADD COLUMN username varchar(200)"` and in `self.down`: `execute "ALTER TABLE reports DROP COLUMN username"` and try!

Comment: Tried to do it with explicit mysql as you suggested - same result.

Answer (score 0):

You're models and migration look fine to me, so my best guess is that you're not using the right command... Are you just using a plain old `rake db:migrate` or something fancier?

Comment: Nothing special. Just `rake db:migrate`